# Who to reset the parameter partially?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

We're working with a data where's a categorical feature just has too huge cardinality, because of a stupid numbering. There are "holes" in the ids, and no guarantee that all new ids will increasing. So to solve this we're thinking on a hashing the ids. But as new ids will come and there will be ids get obsolete and these ids can fall into the same bucket after hashing, so we have to reset the parameters learned with old ids and lear the new ones. But we'd like to keep the other more stable feature's parameters. What's the right way to cleanup the related parameters, but keep the others. Is there any way for that. Or any other solution are welcome.

Comment: So you can develop your hashing technique and rename the categories in ascending order from (say) 0 to N. When you think that the category names need to be rehashed, you can simply re-train only the last layer i.e. the weight matrix between the last fully-connected layer and the classification layer will be re-learned. If it is just re-hashing and there is no change in the underlying data distribution, I think fine-tuning will suffice. No need to re-learn.

Comment: Actually the older categories will be deprecated, so after a while we'll have no data for them. So it makes non sense to keep those parameters. But the better would be so keep the a smaller category size (the active categories are just a few k). And once a while just relearn the related parameters.